# How to get perimeter of components in an image with opencv?

Tags: opencv, python

I have the following matrix:

```
m = np.asarray(
        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ], dtype=np.uint8
)
```

And I apply the following few gradient transforms:

```
gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(m, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, np.ones((2,2),np.uint8))

gradient = cv2.morphologyEx(m, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, np.ones((3,3),np.uint8))
```

And I get the following results, respectively:

[image: 2x2 kernel]

[image: 3x3 kernel]

What I was expecting was the opposite of the image; is there a straight forward, fool-proof way to get the perimeters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the way OpenCV applies the gradient transform.

By running the following command, I was able to obtain the correct result:

```
something = cv2.morphologyEx(m, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, np.ones((3,3),np.uint8))
gradient = something - m
gradient[gradient > 1] = 0
```

Use care copying my answer so that the numbers in the resultant matrix are what you need them to be.